# Can we use ColorPicker in on of the screens in a kv lang and use that in our kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a raspberry pi. I am using a screen manager in kv. There are 4 screens. 1st screen has 3 buttons and other screens have a colorpicker from which I need to take values when the colorpicker is pressed.

I want to use the value from the. Kv file and use it in the py file for furthur processing of the colorwheel. Only valye important to me is colorpicker.value

Answer (score 0):

## User's Kivy App Features

> I am using a screen manager in kv. There are 4 screens. 1st screen has
>   3 buttons and other screens have a colorpicker.

## Solution - ColorPicker & ScreenManager with 1 Screen

Yes, in Python code/script, you can access the selected color of *ColorPicker* widget defined in kv file. Please refer to the small/skeleton example and output for details.

### Note

The *value* of interest is `ColorPicker().color`, `self.color` or `instance.color` in the example.

[Color Picker » color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.colorpicker.html#kivy.uix.colorpicker.ColorPicker.color)

> ```
> color
> ```
>
> The color holds the color currently selected in rgba format.
>
> color is a ListProperty and defaults to (1, 1, 1, 1).

### Snippets

#### kv file

```
<MainScreen>:
    ColorPicker:
        on_color:
            root.on_color(self, self.color)
```

#### Python Script

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def on_color(self, instance, value):
        print("\non_color:")
        print("\tvalue(rgba)={}".format(value))
        print("\tcolor(rgba)={}".format(instance.color))
        print("\tcolor(hex)={}".format(instance.hex_color))
        print("\tcolor(hsv)={}".format(instance.hsv))
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def on_color(self, instance, value):
        print("\non_color:")
        print("\tvalue(rgba)={}".format(value))
        print("\tcolor(rgba)={}".format(instance.color))
        print("\tcolor(hex)={}".format(instance.hex_color))
        print("\tcolor(hsv)={}".format(instance.hsv))


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy ColorPicker Demo"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<ScreenManagement>:
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'

<MainScreen>:
    ColorPicker:
        on_color:
            root.on_color(self, self.color)
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: I think you should let the asker try something, and not directly do his job.